# Finding the union between two arrays (two ranges) in excel and displaying the values they have in common

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, unions

Okay, so this one is a little beyond my scope and I have been unable to find any examples of this (I have searched Google, the Stack, MSDN and several forums).

Lets assume Array1 consists of  values in range A1:A3 one Sheet16 (one column but three rows). This array contains values 1,2,3
Lets also assume Array2 consists of values in ranges A1:C1; values, 1, 2 and 3 (one row but 3 columns).

How would I, see picture below, find the union between the two arrays, and then hide all the columns on sheet 17 that aren't within the union of the two arrays (sets).

In other words, how would I hide column A and column C in sheet 17 (as range B1 contains the union between the two arrays, that being "2".

I know I can establish the two array as follows, I am just unsure where to go from there:

```
Sub Array_123()

Dim myarray As Variant, myarray2 As Variant

myarray = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet16").Range("a1:a3").value)
myarray2 = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet17").Range("a1:c1").value)

End Sub
```

Please see below, any help is greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You want to compare 1 by 1 (if sheet16(A1)<>sheet(A1), HIDE, if sheet16(A2)<>sheet17(B1), HIDE), or you want to compare any value in sheet17 exist in sheet16 ? (if sheet17(A1) not exist in sheet16, HIDE)

Comment: What you are looking for is intersection of sets, not union.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best I have written, but does what I understood you want

1. Explore the List of columns of Sheet17
2. When column header is found in list of values of Sheet16, keep visible otherwise hides (Rank is not longer relevant)

   ```
   Private Sub hideUnmatchCol()

       Dim col As Integer
       Dim rc As Variant

       col = 1

       Do Until Worksheets("Sheet17").Cells(1, col).Value = ""

          On Error Resume Next
          rc = ""
          rc = Worksheets("Sheet16").Columns("A:A").Find(What:=Worksheets("Sheet17").Cells(1, col).Value, _
               After:=Worksheets("Sheet16").Cells(1, 1),  LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
               :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
               False, SearchFormat:=False).Address
          If rc = "" Then
             Worksheets("Sheet17").Columns(col).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
          Else
             Worksheets("Sheet17").Columns(col).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
          End If
          On Error GoTo 0
          col = col + 1
       Loop

   End Sub
   ```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your input. Just wondering though; I am getting a run-time error '9' subscript out of range. Not sure why that would be the case as I have my sheet references correct. Any ideas? Also, it is a coincidence the the values of 2 match and line up (ie value in a2 sheet 16 matches value b1 in sheet 17. When you suggest replacing with a search, could you be so kind as to provide an example of what you mean? I really appreciate your help!! Thank you :)

Comment: On sheet16 I have up to approx. 320 potential values, and on sheet17 I have up to 320 potential values. So sheet16 may have only, say 29 values, while sheet17 will almost always have a fixed amount of values ( which are always in the same place as they are actually column headers) :/

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the problem correctly, you are trying to use sheet 16's values as an index for the columns on sheet 17. If the index matches, column.hidden==False, else column.hidden==True.

Now, this can be accomplished easily using the following approach.

Sub test()

```
Dim myarray As Variant, myarray2 As Variant

'sheet 2 is dictating what happens with the columns on sheet one

myarray = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:d1") '2 dimentional array
myarray2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a1:a4") '2 dimentional array

'check if the arrays are of the same length. We are comparing the rows of one to the columns of the other
If (UBound(myarray2, 1) = UBound(myarray, 2)) Then 'if row length of one is the same as column length of the other
    For arrayIndex = 1 To UBound(myarray2, 1) 'for loop based on the length of the elements in the array
        If (myarray(1, arrayIndex) = myarray2(arrayIndex, 1)) Then 'if the elements at each index point in the arrays have a matching value hide the column
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(arrayIndex).Hidden = True
        End If
    Next arrayIndex
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Did you reconfigure the code to match the structure of your sheets? Of course, I am assuming it is different. What line is the error on?